# Yeoman backbone view not rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, yeoman, backbone-routing

I can't seem to figure out how to show the contents of the mvc files i.e. the views template and the routes.

I have this code in my /routes/application.js

```
sample.Routers = sample.Routers || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    sample.Routers.ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
        '' : function () {
            alert('Home');
        },
        'view': function () {
            alert('View');
        }
    }

    });
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

})();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the router code generated by **yo** when I run the command `yo backbone:all` to this

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({

routes: {
    '' : 'home',
    'view': 'viewImage'
}
});

var appRouter = new AppRouter();

appRouter.on('route:home', function () {
    console.log('im home');
});

appRouter.on('route:viewImage', function() {
    alert('hey');
    // console.log('view');
});


Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```